# WebkitSpeechRecognition Returning Network Error in Electron

Tags: javascript, webkit, chromium, electron, webkitspeechrecognition

Recently (in the past 1.5 weeks) the javascript library WebkitSpeechRecognition has refused to work properly. I've tested other electron applications that utilize the library (smart-mirror by evan cohen) and have run into issues with those.

It throws network errors under every circumstance I've tested it. The library seems to work fine in standard browser environments but I can't seem to get it to work with electron. Does anybody have any experience in wrestling with this?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've posted a question on Google chromium group. 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/JJe6KD7-bb8

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Google has removed this feature for electron. See this [discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/webkitspeechrecognition-google-webkit-speech-api-throws-network-error-in-electron-app/27958).

Comment: I having same issue, I had working last week...so it's not like Google has removed this feature as you mentioned on Apr 28. I stopped working all of sudden

Answer (score 0):

Configure your own Google Speech API credentials using https://console.developers.google.com and then set them on your system's environment variables. I had the same issue and got it working with this way. Make sure to restart your system after configuring the environment variables. Sometimes they don't get into affect immediately.

Please refer for more detailed steps: https://docs.smart-mirror.io/docs/howto/how_to_obtain_chromium_speech_keys.html

[image]

GOOGLE_API_KEY, GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET set their value to Key, ClientID and ClientSecret respectively.

Comment: To a side note we should not be using Speech API for commercial use. This is currently not available to the public use and fix quote of usage.You cannot buy additional quote so beware.

Comment: I don't see how this help to solve the network error in Web Speech Recognition, Google use Cloud Voice Speech now and it seems like they revoked the SpeechRecognition inside embedded chrome app.

Comment: Embedded SpeechRecognition uses Speech API and it has quota limit which cannot be created. Configuring own keys help to get it working for sometime until the quota reaches!

Comment: I configured my keys and it's still doesn't work. This is crazy.. i have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

On some Windows PC's Speech Recognition will work in Edge but not Chrome.  On another PC, seemingly with same software versions, it will not work at all and give NETWORK error.  It's nice when it works, but I don't see how they expect to get any developers for it.  I am developing a free word learning app, not commercial.