# Solutions for voice recognition in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am attempting to find a solution for voice recognition for an AngularJS app I am building for Android and Electron.

I have found a solution for Android in ng-speech-recognition but haven't yet found one for Electron, as most solutions don't work due to Google shutting down the Chrome Speech API (such as electron-speech, which now says the following: It seems that Google has shut down the Chrome Speech API for use in shell environments like Electron, which electron-speech relies on.) .

Due to this, the only solutions seem to be pocketsphinx, which there are multiple npm packages for, but none of which are quite what I'm looking for (for example, one pocketsphinx npm package required me to individually define each word I was planning to recognise syllable by syllable!) or Google Cloud Speech API, which wasn't designed for AngularJS, and the closest example is for node.js, which still isn't something I'm comfortable converting.

Comment: If you're comfortable working with Angular code you could try changing ng-speech-recognition to make requests against the new Google API instead? The API endpoint looks pretty simple, assuming you already have a valid Bearer token.

Comment: I'd have to see how possible that is but thank you for the suggestion, I hadn't thought of that, I was focused on trying to find something new.

Comment: Unfortunately ng-speech-recognition is just a basic wrapper for webkitSpeechRecognition, which is where the actual problem lies, because it uses the Chrome Speech API too. I'll need to find one that doesn't use that API but I've been looking for a while and I don't think it's a problem that is common anymore, so doesn't have a solution as such.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript. check [Aryom.js](https://sdkcarlos.github.io/sites/artyom.html)

Comment: That looks like it uses webkitSpeechRecognition, which OP says is [no longer available in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36214413/243245).